# Why are URP render settings limited in terms of rendering light sources? ( Unity )

Tags: unity, rendering

The amount of simultaneous rendering of multiple lights is not just limited, it is severely limited. Do more than 8 light sources affect the performance so much?

[image]

Comment: Note that you're using a "Forward" renderer. Since this type of renderer needs to re-render the whole object for each light / each small group of lights, it's notorious for performing poorly as the light count increases. This is the reason why "Deferred" rendering was invented, to overcome the severe performance impacts of having many realtime lights. But the memory bandwidth needs of deferred rendering may not be as friendly for the mobile GPUs that URP targets.

Answer (score 1):

The 8-light limit is a hard limit of the Forward Rendering pipeline, and it exists to avoid performance issues such as expensive processing and low frame rates on most devices.

Please note that this is a **per-object** limit, i.e. only up to 8 real-time lights can illuminate a single object. However, you can place as many light sources in your scene as you wish.

During the rendering phase, the engine must:

- Consider each object to render.
- Determine which light sources illuminate the current object.
- Compute lighting for each fragment.

Let \$L\$ be the number of real-time light sources, \$O\$ the number of GameObjects in a scene, and \$P_i\$ the number of fragments the *i*-th object requires for rendering. Then, the number of operations needed to render your scene can be estimated as:

$$
N = L*O*\sum_{i=0}^n P_i
$$

If our scene features 50 lights and 20 objects, we are performing 1000 checks per frame, times the total number of fragments that are to be drawn during the current frame.

If we only consider up to 8 lights per object, we go down to 160 checks per frame, times the total number of fragments. Additionally, we can discard light sources too far from the current object (e.g. light radius is 100 but the distance from object bounds is 300).

Efficiency is key during this phase. Since rendering can become quite expensive, much preprocessing is done per frame so that we draw only what's strictly needed. Stationary objects don't need real-time lights, since they aren't moving. Bake that. Real-time reflections for far away objects are just a waste of resources. Use probes instead.

You can also force real-time lights to only affect moving objects so that GameObjects marked as *Static* will use lightmaps generated from the same light source instead.

---

Such a limit is not uncommon in game engines. Real-time light sources are expensive to compute since lighting happens on a per-[fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_(computer_graphics)) basis. Also, the same game must run on many different devices. That's the reason why many computationally-efficient lighting solutions exist: [baked lights, reflection probes, light probes](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lightmapping.html) (for lighting). The tradeoff here is less precision for more performance, as discussed in this [Unity Forums thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/universal-rp-max-object-lights-limit-problem.907985/) by staff members.